# How can I find and replace strange `unknown replacement` unicode chars?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, unicode

For example i have this line:

```
if (this. != null)
```

When I copy this char  (question mark in a box) and try to find it and to replace it it looks like it's searching for .* and not 

I have few of these in my code and I need somehow to find and remove them.
I think also to remove the point: .

But how to remove them and what to replace them with?

Comment: You need to know the character code to look for it..

Comment: Are these wired chars on a file and you are copying them and placing them?  If yes, just use Notepad++.  Control + 'H' brings the Find Replace menu.

Comment: Seems like you want to get a compilable code from a obfuscated code. Better try to understand what it does and write your own code.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is called the [special replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)). The reason you can't simply search and replace for that value is probably because every one is unique. There are a variety of reason this can happen. Malformed unicode, bad translation between pages, or some other reason.

There is not going to be any way to automatically get rid of these short if figuring out why they were created in the first place.